# flutter packages how to know the properties

Tags: flutter

I am trying to use this package  datetime_picker_formfield 1.0.0 and I want to change the calendar font size and the colors of the whole calendar can anyone tell me from where I can search about the properties of each package? and how I change the colors also I want to add Icon inside the textfiled of the calendar

Comment: if you are using android studio then you can reach to the definition of a widget by highlighting the widget and pressing Ctrl+B . there you can find all the properties that a widget has

Comment: You may also have a look at the documentation from pub.dev: https://pub.dev/documentation/datetime_picker_formfield/latest/datetime_picker_formfield/DateTimeField-class.html

Answer (score 1):

To know about the package & the properties of a package, you should always check the **example** tab in pub.dev .

But all the properties of the package might not be mentioned in the example tab, so, you should explore the package to know more.

How can you explore the package :

- Use your IDE. (For example - If you use VS code you can hover over the definition of the widget/class you are using. By this you can see the properties the widget accepts and try them one by one to understand what they do.)
- Or you can go the definition of the widget and explore.

Now, if the property you want is not provided by the package, then, you can fork the GitHub of the package on to your Github & edit the package with the changes you need.

Comment: I am new to flutter so I read the  definition  but I couldn't figure out how to change the theme of the time picker

Comment: If you are new, i would suggest don't jump to pub.dev packages, instead first explore the widgets. Because internally all the packages make use of the pre-defined widgets provided by flutter.